# Magento 1.7 + onsite paypal

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

Follwoing are the Paypal methods available in New **Magento 1.7**

**PayPal All-in-One Payment Solutions  Accept and process credit cards and PayPal payments.**

**Paypal Payments Advanced (Includes Express Checkout)**

- Basic Settings - PayPal Payments Advanced
- Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout

**Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)**

- Basic Settings - PayPal Payments Pro
- Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout

**Paypal Payments Standard**

- Basic Settings - PayPal Payments Standard

**PayPal Payment Gateways**
**Payflow Pro (Includes Express Checkout)**
 - Basic Settings - PayPal Payflow Pro
 - Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout

**Payflow Link (Includes Express Checkout)**

- Basic Settings - PayPal Payflow Link
- Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout

**PayPal Express Checkout**
 - Express Checkout

Now my question is which one of the above paypal method is useful , if i need to setup my paypal like , customer can enter the CC details on the Checkout and they will not be redirected to paypal .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Paypal Payflow Pro or Paypal Payflow Link.
These options will let your customers pay without leaving your website.

Comment: Thanks , how could i miss that. Do you have any idea how do i disable the Paypal express that comes with it by default or is there any way i can make the express checkout open in popup so that customer will not have to leave the site? 

Thanks

Comment: Go to the configuration and set enable to yes to the method that you want to enable and no to the methods that you do not want.